# How can I change the font color of a row based on a variable?

Tags: visualforce

Let me preface this by saying that this is one my first attempts at coding(on any platform). So what I want to do is change the font color of an entire row if that record looks up to an account that was created within the last 30 days. I attempted to change the values of ech column. Here is a sample of one of the columns.

```
<apex:column>                    
                    <apex:facet name="header">Class Name</apex:facet>
                    <font color="{!if(insa.CustomerID__r.Created_Date_VF__c=TODAY() - 30,'#ff0000','#000000')}">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!insa.Id}" target="_blank" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!insa.Name}"/>
                    </apex:outputLink>
                    </font>
</apex:column>
```

But I am coming to the conclusion that this will have no bearing as I am not displaying the Created_Date_VF__c field. In searching through a ton of posts, it looks as though I may have to append my controller to change the color of the record as it's being queried. Is there another way to do this? Or am I misunderstanding my issue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you querying that field in your controller? I think your approach may work, but it needs be queried.

Comment: Shouldn't that be >=TODAY() - 30?

Comment: Good catch Frank! I will correct that. Daniel, I am querying it in the contoller.

Answer (score 3):

While your code would work, unless you're using an auto-query, it would be better to render this in the controller, because expressions like that cost Visualforce view state size, which is limited (135kb, at the time of this answer). Calculating on the server will also cost view state size indirectly, but substantially less than using an expression. On the other hand, if this table sits outside any form, then view state is of no concern. As you've observed, the usual answers recommend using controller code reasons of view state size and execution performance (executing formulas is slower than Apex Code by a decent margin).

As an aside, you shouldn't be using `font`, but instead using an appropriate style. I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
<!-- somewhere near the top -->
<style>
    .important-text { color: red; }
    .normal-text { color: black; }
</style>

<!-- inside your apex:column -->
<apex:outputLink value="/{!insa.Id}" target="_blank" styleClass="{!styles[insa.id]}">
    <apex:outputField value="{!insa.Name}"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

Where "styles" is defined in the controller as:

```
public Map<Id, String> styles { get; set; }
```

And is populated such that each Id has a corresponding entry based on what color it should be. This should be populated in the controller after performing the query to obtain this data. This will give you better performance overall (faster loading times, less view state) as compared to using a complex expression.

The reason for using CSS is to decouple the business logic from the user interface. For example, say that later you're using #ff0000 all over the page, and you decide to change it to #ff1111 to add a bit of brightness (or something). Now, you've got to search and replace everywhere, while with a style, you change it once and it's done.

Comment: Thanks Fox, I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes. This will be my first time using CSS or the style tag.

Comment: @Brian Just call me Brian, Brian. Best of luck to you on the learning experience.